# Prove that a function that is equal almost everywere to a measurable function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is Lebesgue measurable and for $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $ f = g $ almost everywhere, then $g$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Here is my proof:

Let $E$ be the set such that $f(x) = g(x)\ $ for $x\in[a,b]\backslash E$.
Since $f$ is measurable, the set $$\{x\in[a,b]: f(x) > \alpha \}$$ is measurable, and $$\{x\in[a,b]: f(x) > \alpha \} \cap E^c$$ is also measurable because it is the intersection of measurable sets. Finally $$\{x\in[a,b]: f(x) > \alpha \} \cap E^c = \{x\in[a,b]\backslash E: f(x) > \alpha \} = \{x\in[a,b]\backslash E: g(x) > \alpha \} $$ as required.

Is that correct? I mean I did not use the fact that $m(E) = 0$.

Comment: You have to use the hypothesis somewhere, because all functions are equal somewhere ($\emptyset$!), but not all functions are measurable.

Comment: You have to use that every subset of a measurable set which has zero measure is measurable (and has zero measure too).

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is good. Note that $\{x\in[a,b]: g(x) > \alpha \} = (\{x\in[a,b]: g(x) > \alpha \} \cap E^c) \cup (\{x\in[a,b]: f(x) > \alpha \} \cap E)$. The second set in the union in the RHS is measurable by your argument, and the first set is measurable because is a subset of $E^c$, which has zero measure.